# WiFi soft-blocked by rfkill on startup

Tags: startup, rfkill

I have a small Acer Revo PC with Ubuntu 14.10 that I'm configuring to run as a portable media center.

I'm trying to set it up as a WiFi access point so that I can control XBMC/Kodi with Android devices via an app. This works fine so far.

However, I'm having trouble with the WiFi being soft blocked by rfkill on every startup.

- I tried unblocking it in /etc/rc.local (rfkill unblock wifi) but this doesn't work. Whatever is causing rfkill to block WiFi probably happens after rc.local is finished running.
- If I SSH into the PC fast enough after a reboot, I can see that WiFi actually works for a couple of seconds and then gets blocked. I can see the network on my smartphone as well, but it disappears shortly after showing up.
- I found the file that supposedly stores the rfkill state: /var/lib/rfkill/saved-state. Changing the line to phy0 0 or phy0 1 doesn't solve the problem. Also the file doesn't seem to change at all, so whatever stores the state doesn't work.
- I tried removing the upstart scripts for rfkill (/etc/init/rfkill-[re]store) - no improvement.

What worked for me was the following line in rc.local:

```
sh -c "sleep 10 && rfkill unblock wifi" &
```

But this is a crappy workaround, I have to disable the AP and DHCP services from auto-starting and start them "manually" in rc.local after unblocking WiFi.

What causes rfkill to block things at startup? How do I disable this?

Comment: @adam-monsen Do you have exactly same setup? 14.10 has reached EOL and not supported any more in Ask Ubuntu. Could you put a comment thing that are different from OP case.

Comment: No, I don't. Yeah, I was worried this question was too old. Just seeking a good resolution / workaround. Here's the exact problem I hit today: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143233/wifi-is-sometimes-soft-blocked-by-unknown-service

Answer (score 1):

I was just having this problem and `nmcli r wifi on` solved it. NetworkManager was killing the wifi after startup finished which is why startup script solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: You deserve an upvote buddy. This worked for me and is easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

You have to blacklist the acer-wmi kernel module:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add blacklist acer_wmi as a new line at the bottom of this file.

then reboot.

Or if you like one-line:

```
echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf
```

Other methods:

"Soft blocked" means "blocked by software". A faulty driver or other kernel module can lead to connectivity loss.

Some methods to get WiFi working are described on help.ubuntu.com/

There is also a Launchpad question on this issue: answers.launchpad.net

You can also try a specify device like

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Comment: Thank you!

@M3L, any chance you can confirm this answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - it's been 5 years since I posted this, I don't have that setup any more :/

Comment: Well @AdamMonsen did it work for you since M3L can't confirm , please check it out and the bounty :P

Comment: I'll give the bounty just for the effort and additional attention to this question. I also have no way to confirm.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty . It would be great if could confirm the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

On my acer one blaclisting acer-wmi works but only after installation of firmware-b43-installer package. Dont't ask me why... I noticed it was missing trying to install debian before switching to lubuntu